# Reduce a backbone collection to a set amount

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Hopefully a pretty simple question.

In Backbone.js, how would I go about reducing a collection of unknown length to a set length? So, the collection has 10 models. I want it to be 2. How do I do this? I don't care about the order I'm pulling from the collection, it's been shuffled and should be random, but how do I just reduce the collection down?

Thanks!
Cam

Comment: Did my answer resolve your issue?

Comment: Sorry, I posed my solution below. I ended up solving before I implemented your idea, though from the looks of it, it would work too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [slice](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-slice).

```
var myCollection = new Backbone.Collection(...);
_.each( myCollection.models.slice(-2), function(model) {
    console.log(model.get("id"));
});
```

The `.slice(-2)` will grab the last item and the second to last item. `slice` uses a zero based index and extracts up to, but not including, the value of the last specified index.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better way, but...

```
while (myCollection.size() > 2)
    myCollection.pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet all these answers would work, and they're all so simple to execute that I can't believe I even asked this question, but I ended up solving it this way.

```
for (i=0; i < renderamount; i++){
    shortdata.push(shuffleddata[i]);
}
```

Just build a new array from the old one with a for loop and limit its length to the however many models I need to in my new collection.

Thank you all.